# Java versions problems

Tags: java, java-11

I am trying to compile the project. And I got this error.

```
java: cannot access org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
  bad class file: /C:/Users/TechLine/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.0.0/spring-context-6.0.0.jar!/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.class
    class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

How to solve it???

p.s I already was trying to change java version in java file on java core version(jdk)

Comment: According to the error message (**which does not lie**) you are trying to load classes compiled for Java 17 and later in a Java 11 JVM.  You need to EITHER use a Java 17 JVM to build and run your application, OR switch to a version of Spring that is Java 11 compatible; i.e. Spring 5 and earlier.

Comment: Yeeah, I already tried to switch java versions to 11 and anyway got this message

Comment: If you are using Java 11, you **cannot** use Spring 6.  See the "OR" part of my previous comment.  Spring 6 requires Java 17 or later ... if I am reading the release notes correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your java version dosen't match spring version.

In your error message, you use spring framework 6 but you use java 11.

Spring framework 6 must use java 17 or higher in Spring 6 document.

> https://springframework.guru/getting-ready-for-spring-framework-6/

So If you success compile, **you need to use spring framework 5 or upgrade your java version to 17 or higher.**